# Understanding how to weight variables

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, weights, mathematical-statistics

I am trying to model the "recruitment" of a deer population where recruitment is a factor of "females counted in fall" and "fawns counted in fall". e.g femaleFall:fawnsFall = Recruitment.

In some rows of the data frame I have >/= 100% recruitment where 1 female was counted and 1 fawn was counted, whereas in other rows I have the same result where 200 females were counted and 200 fawns were counted.

I plan to use a GAM model and I would like someone to help me understand how to correctly weight the variable so that recruitment with higher survey counts for fawns and females are weighted more than recruitment where fawns and females were much less.

Can somebody please explain how I would implement this into my model, I am using R for my data analysis.

Thanks